# restricting users from entering into forms

Tags: django, django-models, concurrency, django-views

i am trying to implement some sort of business logic into my django project, of which only 1 instance of an object should be created per parent object. So far , im doing so by hiding the buttons to the create form and showing another update button when the transaction is being done. However , theres a certain scenario that may happen:

1. User A and B are in the same page
2. User A goes into the createview
3. User A fills up the form
4. User B page has not refreshed , clicks into the createview button
5. User A fills up the form , exits , the button switches to the update view
6. user B finishes the form , exits, the button switches to an update view
7. There is now 2 objects being created.

Hence my question , is there a way to lock a createview when a user is inside it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you could lock out the view, for example by looking at this stackoverflow question: [Allow form submission only once a day django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591356/allow-form-submission-only-once-a-day-django)

But you could accomplish your goal in a different way, catch the updateview processing (like the form_valid function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/), and check if an object has already been created with that parent object. If so, return false, and you don't need the hussle with locking and unlocking a view.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is valid, but you shouldn't block this in the view. This should be part of your form validation, since the form should be invalid if it's trying to create an object that already exists.

In your form, override the `clean()` method and raise a `ValidationError` if another object with the same parent already exists. That way, you can display a useful error to the user, e.g. asking the user to refresh the page (which will then hide the form). Your view doesn't need any change since it just renders the invalid form with errors.